# I have an array of numbers that I am trying to sort based on values

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, xlrd

I want to put all the numbers below 12 in one array, all numbers in between 12 and 25 in another array, etc. 
This is the code that I am using, however, I get a bunch of zeros sorted into the arrays.
What can I do to fix my code so I get the values of the array, not a bunch of zeros? 
And I am also using xlrd.
a = int(spread.cell_value(e, y))

```
for a in range(len(arr)):
    if(arr[a] < 12):
        a12.append(spread.cell_value(e, y + 5))
    elif(arr[a] >= 12 and a < 25):
        a25.append(spread.cell_value(e, y + 5))
    elif(arr[a] >= 25 and a < 50):
        a50.append(spread.cell_value(e, y + 5))
    else:
        a99.append(spread.cell_value(e, y + 5))
```

Comment: I don't see where the values for e and y are coming from, or what the cell_value method might return based on their values.. You can also delete the first term from the elif clauses, they're redundant.

Comment: look into `np.digitize`